# find all subset of arrays in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

Here I have written a program that will find all the subsets array, like if the array is `[1, 2, 3]`, and I want output like `[[], 2],, 2, , [2, 1], 3, , [3, 1], [3, 2], [3`

I have written a program that represents the binary logic representation. The output is not coming as expected.

Can you please rectify and modify that programme?

```js
const getAllSubsets = arr => {
    let n = arr.length
    let add = []
    for (let i = 0; i < (1 << n); i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if ((1 << j) & i) {
                add.push([arr[j]])
            }
        }
    }

    return add
}
      
console.log(getAllSubsets([1,2,3]))
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind the output you want. Are you asking for combinations? Permutations? Some random thing with empty elements?

Comment: *"I want output like [[], 2],, 2, , [2, 1], 3, , [3, 1], [3, 2], [3"*: you have an unclosed bracket, a nested array, some lose values, some double commas,... what is this!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two storage arrays: one for all subsets, and one for the current one. The overall schema of your code would be like this:

```
const getAllSubsets = arr => {
    let subsets = []
    
    OUTER LOOP {
        let subset = []
        INNER LOOP {
            if ...
                subset.push(arr[j])
        }
        subsets.push(subset)
    }

    return subsets
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close!  You just put a couple of things in the wrong place.  Here are the fixups:

- You need an array in the outer loop to store all the subsets.  I've called this `allSubsets`.  It will be an array of subsets.  Note: `allSubsets.push(subset)`
- You need a different array on each iteration of the the inner loop.  I've called this `subset`
- You only need to push one element into the subset.  Note: `subset.push(arr[j])`.

```js
const getAllSubsets = arr => {
    let n = arr.length
    let allSubsets = []
    for (let i = 0; i < (1 << n); i++) {
        let subset = []
        for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if ((1 << j) & i) {
                subset.push(arr[j])
            }
        }
        allSubsets.push(subset)
    }

    return allSubsets
}
      
console.log(getAllSubsets([1,2,3]))
```

Answer (score -1):

You could take a recursive approach and get arrays with undefined plus rest and the value plus rest.

```js
const
    getAllSubsets = ([value, ...rest]) => {
       const sub = rest.length ? getAllSubsets(rest) : [[]];
       return [
           ...sub.flatMap(a => [[undefined, ...a]]),
           ...sub.flatMap(a => [[value, ...a]]),
       ];
    };

console.log(getAllSubsets([1, 2, 3]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```